# jquery autocomplete list shows up undesirably on switching browser tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have jquery autocomplete for a text field. It works fine when I enter some text in the box. I choose an option from the suggestion and do something on the page. When I switch browser tab and come back to this page, the autocomplete list shows up again by default which is undesirable. Is there an event I can use to hide the list when the browser tabs are switched?

Comment: is it because it gets focused first or it just does this automatically?

Comment: Need to see your actual code..

Comment: @Keith - the autocomplete list is displayed automatically